# How to handle multiple successive forms and Java objects

Tags: java, forms, session, web-applications, playframework

Suppose I have a pair of forms in a web application each displayed in a separate html file:

`form1.html`

```
<form action="my_controller.java" method="POST">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Next">
</form>
```

`form2.html`

```
<form action="my_controller.java" method="POST">
  Address:<br>
  <input type="text" name="address" value="123 My Way">
  <br>
  Favorite Color:<br>
  <input type="text" name="color" value="Green">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Suppose I also have a Java object:

```
public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String address, String favColor)
```

My question is how am I supposed to handle the submission and control of this form? I entertain the following options:

1. Create a `Person` object on `form1` `POST` and write do DB with empty strings for the remaining fields then update DB on `form2` `POST`
2. Build up the `Person` object client side and create the illusion of new pages with `AJAX`
3. Make use of `sessions` via the controller and pass this information as the user navigates through the forms

It seems like option three is the best solution, though I am not quite sure how to do this. If option 3 is the best practice, how do I do this using the [play framework](https://www.playframework.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First store the two fields `firstname` and `lastname` in the `Person` object, which you received from client in controller.

```
    Person person = new Person();
    person.firstname = fname;
    person.lastname = lname;    
    // Remaining two fields will be null in this point
```

Fill play `Form` with existing person object

`Form<Person> personForm = Form.form(Person.class).fill(person);`

Move to form2 by passing the personForm as argument

`return redirect(views.html.person_form2.render(personForm));`

In your `Form2` make `firstname` and `lastname` hidden and populate their value from `pesronForm` and other two field will be visible as usual and its value left empty.

```
    @(personForm: Form[Person])

    <!-- create hidden field for firstname and lastname like following -->
    <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value='@personForm.field("firstname").value' >
```

Upon submission you will get all the four field values in your controller.

`Form<Person> personForm = Form.form(Person.class)
 Person person = personForm.bindFromRequest().get();`

Comment: Thank you for this response. Is this the most common practice? Or is the AJAX practice more common? I guess less trips to the server would be more efficient, but using AJAX for this seems kind of hacky. Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for accepting, i think this is straight forward way to achieve this. 
I just want to know why you are having two fields in one form and remaining two in other?

Comment: Its because I am building a mobile application using Phonegap, and I'm trying to imitate the mobile experience of small forms that build up. I guess another example would be like filling out an on-line application.

Comment: Got it. Happy Programming.